# Bluetooth is not working on HP 15 da, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth, hp, realtek

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, My Bluetooth was working fine on Windows, but I shifted completely to Ubuntu, and now I cant use my Bluetooth. I am new to Linux, any help in this regard will be appreciated! My hardware: **RTL8821CE**
I have attached screenshots.
[image]

```
$ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5362 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.090350] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    3.675860] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    6.074755] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766913.890:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=936 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.101004] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766913.910:77): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=933 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[    6.150073] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766913.958:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=933 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.354094] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.166:79): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1224 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[    6.355022] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.166:80): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1224 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.369999] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.182:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1228 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.534596] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.350:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1342 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[    6.535209] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.350:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1342 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.546348] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.358:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1343 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Comment: 1. 21.04 is not LTS; 2. 21.04 is EOL. You have to upgrade it to 21.10 and then ask new question.

Comment: Turn on Bluetooth by using the switch at the top (right) of the window. Is your Bluetooth "hardware disabled", i.e., is "Airplane Mode" on?

Comment: There was a mistake, my version is 20.04 LTS not 21.04, sorry for that, the toggle switch for Bluetooth is disabled, I cant turn it on.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: I have updated question with my result,

Comment: @Jeremy31 Please help me fix this issue!

Comment: You may need to reset the BIOS as it isn't showing a bluetooth device present

Comment: @Jeremy31 its still not working

Comment: Try `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` scroll to where "quiet splash" is and make it "quiet acpi_osi='Windows 2015' splash" save, then in terminal do `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Comment: didnt work brother @Jeremy31

Comment: Edit the file again, delete the 'Windows 2015' and make it acpi_osi=Linux then update-grub and reboot